# How to create tcp server with akka?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to create simple tcp server with help of akka.

My main

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress

import akka.actor._
import akka.io._
import Tcp._


object Main extends App {

    implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()

    val serverRef = actorSystem.actorOf(server.Server.props)

    val tcpManager = IO(Tcp)

    tcpManager ! Bind(serverRef, new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8099))


}
```

My server actor:

```
package server

import akka.actor._
import akka.io.Tcp
import Tcp._


object Server {

def props = Props(new Server())

class SimplisticHandler extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case Received(data) => sender() ! Write(data)
        case PeerClosed     => context.stop(self)
    }
}

}

class Server extends Actor {

    override def receive: Receive = {

        case b @ Bound(localAddress) =>
            println(s"connected to ${localAddress.toString}")
            context.parent ! b

        case CommandFailed(_: Bind) => context.stop(self)

        case c @ Connected(remote, local) =>
            val handler = context.actorOf(Server.props)
            val connection = sender()
            connection ! Register(handler)

            case msg =>
                println("Unknown message")
    }

}
```

But when i run it i get dead letter log event:

> table [INFO] [11/08/2019 18:34:11.558]
>   [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://default/deadLetters]
>   Message [akka.io.Tcp$Bound] from
>   Actor[akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0#-176629096] to
>   Actor[akka://default/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters
>   encountered. If this is not an expected behavior then
>   Actor[akka://default/deadLetters] may have terminated unexpectedly.
>   This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings
>   'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bind` message should be sent from an actor. That actor will eventually receive `Bound` message from TCP manager (or `CommandFailed`). In this case, `Server` actor should send `Bind` message. For instance:

```
class Server extends Actor {

    IO(Tcp) ! Bind(self, new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8099)) //<--------

    override def receive: Receive = {

        case b @ Bound(localAddress) =>
            println(s"connected to ${localAddress.toString}")
            context.parent ! b

        case CommandFailed(_: Bind) => context.stop(self)

        case c @ Connected(remote, local) =>
            val handler = context.actorOf(Server.props)
            val connection = sender()
            connection ! Register(handler)

            case msg =>
                println("Unknown message")
    }

}
```